# Convergence in probability: Does squeeze theorem apply?

Tags: convergence, law-of-large-numbers

Does [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) apply in convergence in probability?

My statistics reference (where it talks about convergence in probability and its condition) does not cite it (but does seem to apply it), but it seems like it could apply.

What does the formulation look like for probabilities?

Comment: In full generality, note that if $Y_n\leqslant X_n\leqslant Z_n$ for every $n$ then, for every $\epsilon$, $$[|X_n-L|>\epsilon]\subseteq[|Y_n-L|>\epsilon]\cup[|Z_n-L|>\epsilon],$$ hence, if $Y_n\to L$ in probability and  $Z_n\to L$ in probability then, indeed, $X_n\to L$ in probability.

Answer (score 2):

Another version, just because I like the approach

$f_n\stackrel{p}{\to} L$ if and only if every subsequence $f_{n_k}$ has a subsubsequence $f_{n_{k_i}}$ that converges almost surely to $L$

Almost-sure convergence clearly satisfies the squeeze theorem.

If $X_n\leq Y_n\leq Z_n$ and $X_n, Z_n\stackrel{p}{\to} L$, then every subsequence has a subsubsequence where the convergence is almost-sure and thus along that subsubsequence $Y_n\stackrel{as}{\to} L$. But that is just to say $Y_n\stackrel{p}{\to}L$.

As an additional note: both these proofs actually only need $P(X_n\leq Y_n\leq Z_n)\to 1$.  You might argue that's the 'real' squeeze theorem in probability.

Comment: This is ingenious. +1.

Answer (score 0):

$f_n \xrightarrow{p} L$ means, for any $\epsilon > 0$, that

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}\left( \left|f_n - L \right| < \epsilon \right) = 1.
\end{equation*}

If you have $X_n \leq Y_n \leq Z_n$ for every appropriate $n$ then $X_n - L \leq Y_n - L\leq Z_n - L$ for any $L$.  Take each of those differences to be nonnegative for simplicity; then for any $\epsilon > 0$,

\begin{equation*}
\left\{\left|Z_n - L\right| < \epsilon\right\} \subseteq \left\{\left|Y_n - L\right| < \epsilon\right\} \subseteq \left\{\left|X_n - L\right| < \epsilon\right\}.
\end{equation*}

You thus have that $\mathbb{P}(|Z_{n} - L| < \epsilon) \leq \mathbb{P}(|Y_n - L| < \epsilon) \leq \mathbb{P}(|X_n - L| < \epsilon)$, and the standard squeeze theorem gives you the result you're looking for.

Comment: The assumption that the differences have the same sign is unwarranted and it invalidates the approach suggested.

Comment: Indeed, the correct argument should be:

$$P(|X_n-L|>\epsilon)\leq P(|Y_n-L|>\epsilon)+P(|Z_n-L|>\epsilon),$$

and now the two terms on the right can be simultaneously made arbitrarily small for $n$ large enough.